# In outlook add-ins make salesforce oauth2 auth request getting CORS error

Tags: salesforce, outlook-web-addins, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I have developed react js framework outlook add-ins , In that i need to add salesforce log in , so i was make the salesforce oauth2 auth request from client Side getting the cors error

i have tried the jsforce script , This is solve this issue but in this refresh token not getting

i have added the cors Allowed origins in salesforce still i am getting error

[image][image]

Any thoughts about this please share me

Note : **Add-ins developed using javascript and this issue occur on local environment**

Comment: Can you please explain the steps how you are trying this??

Comment: Sure , I have added salesforce log in my add-ins so i made authorize request to salesforce using rest API "/services/oauth2/authorize" this path getting cors error

Comment: Can you help us with the snippet you're trying, this will enable us to help you better?